# between 8:00 am to 8:30 am

Tags: word-choice

Pick up the paperwork between 8:00 am to 8:30 am.  Is the word "to" incorrect?  I was informed by a coworker that it should read "between 8:0 am and 8:30 am." If a correction is needed, can you tell me why. Thank you for your input.

Comment: From X to Y. Between A and B. Not the other way around. Such is idiomacy. I can think of no language, actually, where _to_ is used with _between_, rather than _and_.

Comment: Whether it's accurate to call the wrong choice of a preposition a grammatical error [previous question] is arguable. But whatever we call it, it's an error.